# Get-PrimaryKey : Cannot find primary key property for type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

Add Code Generation Item...

```
Added DbContext Generator
```

The class below was created for my tables(Course,Lecture,Student) called "Management":

```
public class Management
    {
        public class Course
        {

            public int CourseId { get; set; }
            public string CourseName { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; } 
            public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Lecture> Lectures { get; set; }
        }
        public class Lecture
        {

            public int LectureId { get; set; }
            public String LectureName { get; set; }
            public String Description { get; set; }
            public int CourseId { get; set; }
            [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("CourseId")]
            public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        }
        public class Student
        {

            public int StudentId { get; set; }
            public String FirstName { get; set; }
            public String LastName { get; set; }
            public int CourseId { get; set; }
            [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("CourseId")]
            public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

In the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Scaffold Controller Management
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Get-PrimaryKey : Cannot find primary key property for type 'RBS.PFM.Models.Management'. No properties appear to be primary keys.
At C:\Projects\RBS Project\RBS.PFM\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.9\tools\Controller\MvcScaffolding.Controller.ps1:71 char:15
+ $primaryKey = Get-PrimaryKey $foundModelType.FullName -Project $Project -ErrorIf ...
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-PrimaryKey], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.GetPrimaryKeyCmdlet
```

Can anyone please suggest the best way to resolve this.

Kind Regards,
Sindhuja